# Can not upload a file containing "[" in the name to IBM Cloud Object Storage

Tags: c#, ibm-cloud, object-storage

I tried uploading to IBM Cloud Object Storage (ICOS) with the following code, and some files could not uploaded.
Failed files contain the symbol "[" or "]" in the file name.

```
TransferUtility Utl = new TransferUtility(objClient);
TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest request = new   TransferUtilityUploadDirectoryRequest
{
    BucketName = "Correct Backet name"
    Directory = "Correct directory name" ex. "C:\\testd1\\testd2"
    KeyPrefix = "Correct prefix"
    SearchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories,
    SearchPattern = "*.*"
};

Utl.UploadDirectory(request);
```

---

Language:.NET C#

API: AWSSDK.Core 3.3.22.5, AWSSDK.S3 3.3.18.2

Exception name：Amazon.S3.AmazonS3Exception
Message："Invalid Argument"

InnerException name：Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException
Message："The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

Files with ordinary name such as "test.txt" can be uploaded without problems.
This phenomenon does not occur with AWS S3 or another S3 compatible storage service.
(But I have tried on only one of other S3 compatible services...)

Could you tell me  why I can not upload to ICOS and what solutions are there?

Best Regards.

Comment: Personally, I'd look at hashing the filename, or stripping out non-alphanumeric characters. Would that work? My C# is unfortunately weak so I can't provide an example of how you'd do that, but it's likely good practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a case of AWS not strictly enforcing their published restrictions. Per the [AWS S3 docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html), "Avoid the following characters in a key name because of significant special handling for consistency across all applications."

- Backslash ("\")
- Left curly brace ("{")
- Non-printable ASCII characters (128–255 decimal characters)
- Caret ("^")
- Right curly brace ("}")
- Percent character ("%")
- Grave accent / back tick ("`")
- Right square bracket ("]")
- Quotation marks
- 'Greater Than' symbol (">")
- Left square bracket ("[")
- Tilde ("~")
- 'Less Than' symbol ("<")
- 'Pound' character ("#")
- Vertical bar / pipe ("|")

If URL encoded (`[object-key]` -> `%5Bobject-key%5D`) everything should be fine.  The `UrlEncode(string)` method from the `HttpUtility` class might help ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httputility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Web_HttpUtility_UrlEncode_System_String_)).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice.

I would like to do the following:
- The names of the upload source files contains the symbols "[" and "]", but I do not want to change the file name.
However, the uploaded destination file name (= object key?) can be changed.
- I would like to upload the files using the "UploadDirectory" method .

I searched a way how to upload by the "UploadDirectory" method with specifying the key name of the object to be created on the bucket.
But I did not arrive at a good way.

I think that using the "UploadDirectory" method, I can not specify the key name of the object to be created.
(Therefore, I think that encoding can not be done.)

On ICOS, is it impossible to upload files containing "[" or "]" in the file name using the "UploadDirectory" method?